# Qual a diferença entre @Inject e @EJB na injeção de um EJB?

Tags: java, ejb, injeção-de-dependência

Tenho um EJB que depende de outro EJB, então vou usar injeção de dependência para satisfazer essa dependência. A minha dúvida é: qual a diferença, vantagem ou desvantagem entre @Inject e @EJB.

Comment: Muito bom @Wakim. Você acha que seria legal ver as diferenças e colocar aqui para o público brasileiro?

Comment: Esta pergunta é sobre uma linguagem de programação específica? Se sim, adicione a tag da linguagem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para o Java EE 6 ou 7, a recomendação é tentar sempre utilizar `@Inject`, anotações `@EJB` devem ser utilizadas somente quando uma funcionalidade sem contrapartida na anotação `@Inject` for necessária.

A ideia é que com as JSRs [299](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=299) (CDI) e [300](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330) (DI) a anotação `@Inject` se tornou um mecanismo unificado, disponível para todas as camadas da aplicação, substituindo as anotações anteriores específicas de tecnologias como EJB e JSF.

Dito isso, para alguns casos você acaba tendo que utilizar as anotações da tecnologia raiz.

Para a anotação `@EJB` existem alguns casos típicos de uso como:

- Dependências circulares (injetar um EJB dentro dele mesmo é um *workaround* popular quando há demarcação transacional declarativa a ser respeitada entre métodos da mesma classe)
- Convivência com mapeamentos *nonstandard*, EJBs remotos, etc. As coisas no mundo EJB foram sendo padronizadas aos poucos, quem sobreviveu a era do Java 1.4 sabe bem que cada servidor de aplicação possuía sua própria maneira de expor EJBs, suas próprias convenções, etc. A anotação EJB conta com parâmetros como `beanName`, `lookup` e `mappedName` para lidar com essas variações.

---

**Fontes**:

- [ADAM BIEN'S WEBLOG - @INJECT VS. @EJB](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/inject_vs_ejb)
- [SOEn - What is the difference between @Inject and @EJB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889767/what-is-the-difference-between-inject-and-ejb)
- [SOEn - Should I use @EJB or @Inject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138232/should-i-use-ejb-or-inject)

Comment: +1, Somente complementando: comparando em um application server, não existe muita diferença em relação a performance que justifique que CDI beans são mais "leves" que EJBs.